# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Tags: php, query, errors

```
<?php if(empty($username)) {array_push($errors, "Username is required")}; ?>
```

i put this line inside a php file but there is a problem with it, can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try this `<?php if(empty($username)) {array_push($errors, "Username is required");} ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced `;` in your code, it should be

```
<?php if( empty( $username ) ) { array_push( $errors, "Username is required" ); } ?>
```